# Are there any clustering algorithms that produce monotone clusters?

Tags: python, clustering

My dataset contains two variables:
y - a binary indicator of an event.
score - the log odds ratio obtained from a logistic regression.

I need to cluster the the score variable to produce 20 clusters, each of which will have a specified average score and event rate. One crucial restriction is that the event rate and score curves by cluster needs to be monotone, meaning that as the cluster number goes up so do the average values of both variables.
So far I have tried doing this with k-means, but the results obtained violate the aforementioned condition.

Can anyone recommend any clustering algorithms, which could account for the monotonicity restriction(preferably in python)?

Comment: If you apply k-means to the sore values, your condition must automatically be fulfilled provided the logistic regression makes any sense. How can this codnition be violated?

Comment: It will only be automatically fulfilled if the regression has an accuracy ration equal to 1, which is unrealistic. My regression has an AR equal to 0.72 and can very well have slight inversions in the average event rate/score value, especially in clusters where the event rate is low and not many observations are present.

Comment: Have you tried the binning by quantiles, as it is done in the Hosmer-Lemeshov test? This should avoid the problem of sparse clusters: actually all clusters will contain the same number of points. An alternative would be to not use logistic regression, but the probability $P(Y=1|x)$ as estimated form a conditional density plot.

Comment: I used to do this clustering manually by first splitting the dataset into 50 quantiles and then manually combining them until the required conditions are met, however this approach has the drawback of ignoring dense clusters of observations, which is not ideal. Using probability instead of score in this context is not possible due to methodological constrains.